# How can I apply HSTS header to all vhosts over 443 in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, https, httpd.conf, http-headers, hsts

I'm looking to add the HSTS header in Apache...

```
# HSTS / Header Strict Transport Security
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
```

... but I have a long list of vhosts for different but related sites/sub-sites.  I'd rather not have to define it in every one of my vhost definitions, but I'm not aware of a way to include a setting in the main `https.conf` that ONLY applies to the `443 / https` versions of those vhosts since it raises warnings in validators when you apply HSTS to a standard `80 / http` site.

I've tried wrapping it in `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>...</IfModule>` tags but if I'm not mistaken, this is really just asking *Is the SSL module loaded?*  I tried searching lots of different ways, but when you don't know the term your looking for, it's difficult to sort through all the static.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [`<If>` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) and the [Expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) available; *request related [variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars)*:

- `REQUEST_SCHEME`: The scheme part of the request's URI

  ```
  <If "%{REQUEST_SCHEME} == 'https'">
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
  </If>
  ```
- `HTTPS`:    `on` if the request uses https, `off` otherwise

  ```
  <If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
  </If>
  ```

Comment: Thanks very much for that, I'd used them in PHP many times before forgetting that they came from Apache!  One note, the value for `REQUEST_SCHEME` should be lower case `https`, it won't ever match `HTTPS`. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've updated the lowercase `https`.